# TFS Work Item vs Requirement

Tags: tfs

I'm working in TFS 2015. We are currently duplicating the same content to populate a Work Item Request as well as a Requirement and linking the requirement as a child to the WIR. How are these two different and how should they be used?

Comment: Which process are you using in TFS? Are you using CMMI?Did you mean the work item change request for work item request? What's the WIR mean in your question, Work Item Request?

Answer (score 0):

**Requirement** is a work item type in TFS CMMI process. Which represents **a description of what your application should do to solve a customer problem.**

[image]

A team can use requirements to describe scenarios and quality of service, safety, security, functional, operational, and user interface criteria.

**Change request** to **manage  proposed changes** to any work product that is under **change control.** It is the same as a Requirement when it comes to planning, tracking and execution. We usually link task as a child to the change request work item type, the same level as Requirement. For more details about change request you could refer below two links:

- [Manage change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/cmmi/guidance-manage-change)
- [Change request field reference (CMMI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/guidance/cmmi/guidance-change-request-field-reference-cmmi)